# How to array after object in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have array but i need to join object after array

my array

```
const users = [
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
    ]
```

my object

```
{ street: true }
```

result i need

```
[
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
    ], { street: true }
```

Comment: please clarify result you need.
do you need result in this way: 
[
[
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
    ], { street: true } ]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join then up like an array you can do

```js
const newArray = [users, { street: true }]
```

Otherwise if you want to join them up as a new object do

```js
const newObject = {
  residents: users,
  info: { 
    street: true
  }
}
```

like @AT-martins suggested

Answer (score 0):

so you need an object with 2 properties, one could be called "residents" and the other "info", the structure would look like this:

```js
{
 residents: [
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
  ],
  info: { 
    street: true
  }
}
```

I think this is the easiest way to have your array and your object in one single data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `push()` for this.
So you have this array:

```js
const users = [
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
    ]
```

And you want to attach this:

```js
const anotherObj = { street: true };
```

Then you can use this:

```js
const users = [
      {name: "Joe", age: 22},
      {name: "Kevin", age: 24},
      {name: "Peter", age: 21}
    ];
const anotherObj = { street: true };
users.push(anotherObj);
```

This will do the job!
But, the above is the solution if you want that object to go inside the array. If you want to make a new array, you can do this:

```js
const arr = [users, anotherObj]
```

This will make a new array with the users array in index 0 and the obj at index 1